# Empty Text Fields Not Being Labeled in Document AI Custom Processor HITL UI

Tags: cloud-document-ai

When reviewing auto-labeled documents in the HITL or labeling training interface, I'm not clear from Google's instructions whether to identify empty fields on a form. For example, if I have these fields:

[image: Example empty text fields]

Should I leave them unlabeled since they don't have values, or draw the bounding boxes that identify where a value would be and leave the text value blank like this?

[image: Example empty text fields labeled]

I'm reviewing auto-labeled forms and seeing these blank fields unlabeled frequently, and I'm not sure if I'm helping to improve the model by drawing the bounding boxes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have almost ZERO skills here :-) ... however, my gut is saying that you would leave them unlabelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed with the Product Managers, you should leave empty fields unlabeled when creating training data for a Custom Processor (Uptraining or Custom Document Extractor)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I may have missed it, but I didn't see that here, and it would have been helpful in terms of the overall labeling instructions: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/label-documents